# Way to add Multiple secret in azure KeyVault using Powershell in 1 go

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-keyvault

```
$devices = @{ dev1 = "mac"; dev2 = "ipod"; dev3 = "ipad"; dev4 = "samsung"}
$osdev = @{ os1 = "osx"; os2 = "ios"; os3 = "ios"; os4 = "android"}

foreach ($osdevi in $osdev.values){

    $hashed=ConvertTo-SecureString -String $osdevi -AsPlainText -Force
    Set-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName 'JonnyKv' -Name $devices.values -Secretvalue $hashed.Values 

}
```

Facing issues with the above code as **devices** in a secret Name and **osdev** is the Secret Value. Need the values to be added in 1 go via PowerShell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways you could approach it. An easy and common way would be to use a CSV format.

```
$csv = @'
type,os
"mac","osx"
"ipod","ios"
"ipad","ios"
"samsung","android"
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

foreach ($device in $devices.GetEnumerator()){

    $hashed = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $device.OS -AsPlainText -Force
    Set-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName 'JonnyKv' -Name $device.type -Secretvalue $hashed

}
```

You could also just make your initial hashtables arrays instead and use a for loop

```
$devices = "mac","ipod","ipad","samsung"
$osdev = "osx","ios","ios","android"

for($i = 0; $i -lt $devices.count; $i++){

    $hashed = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $osdev[$i] -AsPlainText -Force
    Set-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName 'JonnyKv' -Name $devices[$i] -Secretvalue $hashed

}
```

Or you could combine the hashtables

```
$devices = @{
    type = "mac"
    os   = "osx"
    },
    @{
    type = "ipod"
    os   = "ios"
    },
    @{
    type = "ipad"
    os   = "ios"
    },
    @{
    type = "samsung"
    os   = "android"
    }

foreach ($device in $devices.GetEnumerator()){

    $hashed = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $device.OS -AsPlainText -Force
    Set-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName 'JonnyKv' -Name $device.type -Secretvalue $hashed

}
```

Comment: The  code makes sense but ` $device = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $device.os -AsPlainText -Force` i need to add **device.os** to secure string. Thats where i am facing issues

Comment: You're wanting to make the OS the passwords?

Comment: yes i am wanting to make the os as the password and it needs to go in as a secure string thats the validation of the secret value in an Azure Keyvault